# C++ Function Exercise - Keeps returning zero

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, reference

Total beginner.

The exercise is to make a function that takes an input and if the input is even, a certain calculation is done. If odd, a calculation is done. Then the new value is reassigned and the sequence continues until 1 is reached.

Example:
If the starting integer is 1, the return value should be 0, since it takes no steps to reach one. If the starting integer is 3, then the sequence would go: 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, and the return value should be 7.

Been messing with this for hours and I keep getting a return of 0 from counter.

(The main() is used only for testing purposes)

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int hailstone(int outinput);

int main()
{
  int outinput=10, counter;

  hailstone(outinput);

  cout << counter << endl;

  return 0;
}

int hailstone(int outinput)
{
  int counter;

  for(outinput; outinput == 1; )
  {
    if(outinput % 2 == 0)
    {
      outinput = outinput / 2;
      counter++;
    }
    else if(outinput % 2 != 0)
    {
      outinput = outinput * 3 + 1;
      counter++;
    }
  }

  return counter;
}
```

Comment: the counter in your main function and the counter in your hailstone function are two separate entities. Modifying one doesn't modify the other. Also `for(outinput; outinput == 1;)` essentially means this only runs if outinput is 1. Also, if you wanted the loop to run until the value reached 1 it would be better phrased as a while loop: `while( outInput != 1 )`

Comment: I think the misconception here is over whether an identically-named variable in two functions will represent the same value.

Comment: And a bigger mistake here is *running the program* before *fixing the compiler warnings*.  It's odd to ignore advice and then ask for more.

Comment: @DrewDormann But it's so tasty!

Comment: Got it @RyanP thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not receiving what `hailstone()` returns.

Do this:

```
counter = hailstone(outinput);
```

In method `hailstone` you increment `counter` without initializing it. This will lead you to get undefined behaviour.

Initialize `counter` in method `hailstone`

```
int counter = 0;
```

And finally your for loop termination condition: `outinput == 1` is wrong. This condition means the loop will iterate only if `outinput` is `1`. Use `outinput != 1` means you loop will iterate until `outinput` becomes `1`.

[Live run here.](http://ideone.com/zTQZ2P)

Comment: But also, hailstone() only returns something by accident, not reliably by design.  To connect `counter` in the hailstone to `counter` in main, hailstone must `return counter;` and (as you said) main must receive it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the return value of `hailstone` into a variable or `cout << hailstone(outinput) << endl;`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int hailstone(int outinput);

int main(){
    int outinput=10, counter;
    counter = hailstone(outinput); // You need to put the return value of hailstorm into a variable
    cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}

int hailstone(int outinput){
    int iterations = 0;             // You need to initialize counter to 0
    while (outinput != 1){          // you had the wrong condition. (your's ran only when outinput equals 1. You wanted the opposite). Also a while loop works better in this case.
        ++iterations;
        if(outinput % 2 == 0){
            outinput = outinput / 2;
        } else if(outinput % 2 != 0) {
            outinput = outinput * 3 + 1;
        }
    }
    return ++iterations;
}
```

The counter in hailstorms is not the same as counter in your main. For added clarity i changed the counter variable in hailstorm to be named iterations (IE the number of iterations done by the for/while loop).

You also need to make sure you initialize your variables before you use their values.